# Como pesquisar qualquer parte da string com mysql

Tags: mysql

Olá, eu uso esta forma para pesquisar no MySQL `string%`, porém em uma frase "teste um dois três" se eu usar `ste%` ele nao vai retornar a frase, como eu poderia pesquisar se contém dentro da frase?

Comment: Tente utilizar  `%ste%`

Comment: Qual a intenção de por o % no final da string de busca, se o que varia no seu exemplo é o começo? O % é o coringa, se quer achar coisas que mudam dos dois lados, tem que por % dos dois lados, como disse o @Maurivan. No seu caso, se procurar "test%" vai encontrar, pois começa com "tes". Se procurar por  "%rês" também, pois termina com "rês" a frase. Note a diferença de posição do %

Comment: @Bacco Mas por exemplo, em uma string "Wolverine", quero que ao pesquisar `veri` já resulte em Wolverine, como posso fazer isso ??

Comment: LucasCarezia exatamente o que o @Maurivan já disse,  `campo LIKE "%veri%"` pondo um % antes e um % depois

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já que o que você quer não começa com **ste** não adianta você realizar um select assim `ste%` pois ele irá te retornar tudo que começar com **ste** seguido de qualquer coisa.

Para poder pegar tudo que contenha apenas **ste** o seu select terá que ter `%ste%`

`select coluna from tabela where coluna like %ste%`